# Prevent nested paragraphs with ngx-translate in Angular 13

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

We use ngx-translate to provide multi-language support in an Angular 13 application. This works like a charm except when multiple paragraphs are defined in a translation string. For example the translation ID `MULTILINE` has the definition:

```
"MULTILINE": "<p>Paragraph 1</p><p>Paragraph 2</p>"
```

When using this in the HTML template I need to use `innerHTML` as the translation contains HTML I don't want to get stripped:

```
<p [innerHTML]="'MULTILINE' | translate"></p>
```

In the resulting dom I get (formatting added for readability):

```
<p>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</p>
```

How can I prevent the outer `p` element from appearing? It doesn't matter if the translation string contains the begin/end `p` tags.

Comment: You can use the `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML` to replace the `<p>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Amer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15159603/amer) you need to use `outerHTML` instead of `innerHTML`. This **does** require the proper use of tags in the translation strings.